# how to print white space if i uncheck the checkbox and when if i check split by (", ")

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, database

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="1" tabindex="-1">
        <input type="checkbox" id="Speaker1" class="chkCris" value="1" />1</li>
            <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="2" tabindex="-1">
                <input type="checkbox" id="Speaker2" class="chkCris" value="2" />2</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="6" tabindex="-1">
                <input type="checkbox" id="chkOthers" class="chkCriOthers" value="Others" />&nbsp;Others, please explain</a> </li>
            <li><div id="divOthers" style="display: none; font-size: 14px; text-align: left;"><a id="A1" href="#" class="small" data-value="7" tabindex="-1">
        <input class="input-xxlarge" id="textboxOthers" name="textboxOthers" type="text"                              placeholder="Others, please explain" ></a> 
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>

function getValueCriteriaSpeaker()
{
    /* declare an checkbox array */
    var chkArray = [];
    $(".chkCris:checked").each(function () {
        chkArray.push($(this).val());
    });

    if (document.getElementById("chkOthers").checked == true)
    {
        var otherscriteria = document.getElementById("textboxOthers").value;
        chkArray.push(otherscriteria);
    }

    // ....
```

so how to print white space if i uncheck checkbox?
for example: for value 2 is uncheck (print whitespace) -> 1, , others

Comment: having inputs in anchor tag is bad, very bad

Comment: another is if you'r using jQuery, then stick to jQuery  don't mix jQuery with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Though question is not very clear, but here is my implementation for your problem

```js
function getValueCriteriaSpeaker(){
     var values = $("ul.dropdown-menu :checkbox:checked").map(function(i,cb){ return $(cb).val();});
     var str = values.get().join($('#useComma').is(':checked') ? ',' : ' ');
    
      $('#textboxOthers').val(str);
  }

$('.chkBox').on('change',getValueCriteriaSpeaker)
$('#useComma').on('change',getValueCriteriaSpeaker)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>
  <input type="checkbox" id="useComma"/> 
  Split By "," (Comma)
</span>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="Speaker1" class="chkBox" value="1" />1</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="Speaker2" class="chkBox" value="2" />2</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" id="chkOthers" class="chkBox" value="Others">Others</li>
            <li>
              <div id="divOthers">
                  <input class="input-xxlarge" id="textboxOthers" name="textboxOthers" type="text"                              placeholder="Others, please explain"/>
               </div>
            </li>
</ul>
```